# Do I need to use stationary time series data when building linear model with AR error terms?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

I have a linear model $y=\beta*x+\epsilon$. However, the error term is modeled as an AR term, where $\epsilon(t)=p*\epsilon(t-1)+w(t)$, $w(t)$ is white noise. Y and X are both time series economic variables.

ADF test shows that both x and y are non-stationary. Johansen test cannot reject the null there are cointegration in between the two variables.

What is the assumption behind?

Is stationarity required on x and y to start with such model?

Comment: No, all you need is that $x$ and $y$ are cointegrated - which is sufficient for $\epsilon$ to be stationary.  I suggest plotting the residuals from the simple regression and seeing whether they look stationary; that, plus the results of your Johansen test, assuming you have enough data so there is some power behind it, should give you some confidence that a linear model with AR terms won't run into problems due to nonstationarity.

Comment: I ran OLS lm(y~x), adf test cannot reject the null that residual is none-stationary. In this case, does it mean the AR residual terms probably has issues?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot convert "cannot reject the null" into "probably the null is true".  If you have a LOT of data, you could informally work as though that were the case, but if you don't, the power of the ADF test may not be great enough to reject a quite incorrect null (if gradations of "incorrect" are permissible) very often.

Comment: Also note that the critical values are different when you test for a unit root in the residuals (essentially testing for absence of cointegration) than when you test it in an original series. Have you adjusted for that?